# How can I pass a variable ID for the YouTube API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am new to CS and currently working on personal projects. I am creating a web app where a user can copy and paste a YouTube URL to a video in a search box and then have the ability to watch the video on the same web page after clicking watch. To get the video ID, I have used a regex:

```
function getId(url) {
        const regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|&v=)([^#&?]*).*/;
        const match = url.match(regExp);

        return (match && match[2].length === 11)
          ? match[2]
          : null;
      }
```

And this is how I am getting the user input:

```
var inputVal = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
```

To get the video ID, I am calling `getId` on the `inputVal` from the user:

```
  var newVideoId = getId(inputVal)
```

Below is the YouTube API used to play a video on my page. However, I am finding it difficult to passing in the `newVideoId` variable to the API under the `player` object.

```
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
        //    after the API code downloads.
        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
          player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'newVideoId', //the problem lies here
            events: {
              'onReady': onPlayerReady,
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
          });
        }

        // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
          event.target.playVideo();
        }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
            }
```

The problem is that, nothing shows on my screen after clicking the button. I am able to `console.log` the ID; that means I am getting the correct ID from the regex equation.

I would appreciate any help on how to use a dynamic ID gotten from user in the API! Thanks

Comment: `videoId: newVideoId` (remove the quotes, you had text there, not the variable)

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but it did not work!

Comment: "Did not work" isn't very helpful as a problem description :) If the code that loads the Youtube player runs before the user fills out the form, this will obviously not work because `newVideoId` doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

To play a video with the iframe api providing a video Id you can use this function:

```
loadVideoById({'videoId': 'bHQqvYy5KYo',
           'startSeconds': 5,
           'endSeconds': 60,
           'suggestedQuality': 'large'});
```

From IFrame Player API:

> This function loads and plays the specified video.
>
> The required videoId parameter specifies the YouTube Video ID of the
> video to be played. In the YouTube Data API, a video resource's id
> property specifies the ID. The optional startSeconds parameter accepts
> a float/integer. If it is specified, then the video will start from
> the closest keyframe to the specified time. The optional endSeconds
> parameter accepts a float/integer. If it is specified, then the video
> will stop playing at the specified time.

This should do the trick.